# System.Widows.Shapes.Path into System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicPath

Tags: vb.net, winforms, system.drawing

is there way to perporm converting like this?

```
System.Widows.Shapes.Path into System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicPath
```

I want to draw my Windows.Shapes.Path into Bitmap:

```
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(300, 300)
Dim g As System.Drawing.Graphics
g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
g.DrawPath(New System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black), myPath)
```

Or, may be, are some ways to perform inserting Windows Shapes into Image?

Comment: No. `System.Windows.Shapes.Path` belongs to WPF, which does not care about `System.Drawing` at all. You're mixing two completely different technologies. One of them is deprecated... guess which one...

Answer (score 0):

Use `Path.Data.GetFlattenedPathGeometry` to get an approximation of the Path consisting of many small line segments. Loop through the `PathFigures` and `Segments` to extract all the point, and use them to recreate the `GraphicPath`.

Since you're rendering this into a bitmap in the end, the loss of accuracy won't matter.